# How to draw a vector in Cartesian coordinate system by ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a vector with point P(2,4) and point Q(-4,-6). I can easily write this in base plot system.

```
arrows(0, 0, 2, 4, angle=20) # command to draw vector as arrows. 
arrows(0, 0, -4, -6, angle=20) # with angle of the arrow
```

However, when I want to transform this to ggplot2, I don't know how to continue.

```
x1 <- c(0,2,-4)
y1 <- c(0,4,-6)
df <- data.frame(x1,y1)

ggplot(df) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1))
```

Comment: In this case, a picture of current and expected plots would be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of other geoms besides `geom_point`, check out the reference for other possible geoms that might draw segments: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/

Comment: sorry, @NelsonGon , because I'm a new beginner to use the stackoverflow, I don't know how to paste the expected plots,I want to draw two vectors(linear algebra), one is from the origin(0,0) to point(2,4), another is from the origin(0,0) to point(-4,-6)

Comment: @NelsonGon
the whole code to produced the expected plot       
 plot(0, 0, xlim=c(-6,6), ylim=c(-6,6),main="Cartesian Coordinate System")                  



grid()          

abline(h=0)          
abline(v=0)          

text(2,4,"P")              

text(-4,-6,"Q")           

arrows(0, 0, 2, 4, angle=20) # command to draw vector as arrows.    
arrows(0, 0, -4, -6, angle=20) # with angle of the arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt:

```
      library(tidyverse)
      x=c(-6:6)
      y=c(-6:6)
      df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y))+geom_abline(aes(slope=0,intercept=0))+
  annotate("text",x=2,y=4,label="P",size=9,colour="red")+
  annotate("text",x=-4,y=-6,label="Q",colour="red",size=9)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  geom_point(aes(x=0,y=0))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=2,yend=4),
               arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.5,"cm"),angle=20),lineend = "butt")+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=-4,yend=-6),
               arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.5,"cm"),angle=20),lineend = "butt",linejoin = "round")+
  theme_minimal()
```

Plot:
[image]

Comment: looks like you're missing the segment from the origin to point Q.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot. @NelsonGon @ OTStats

Comment: You're Welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `geom_segment` instead of `geom_point`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 2, yend = 4)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = -4, yend = -6))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help, I want to draw two vectors(linear algebra), one is from the origin(0,0) to point(2,4), another is from the origin(0,0) to point(-4,-6)

Comment: Simply add a new `geom_segment` call to your plot. I'll edit answer.

Comment: Thank you. Great job, it completely solved my plotting problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geom_vector` from the `ordr` package.

Check [here](https://corybrunson.github.io/ordr/reference/geom_vector.html)  for the official documentation.

You can write:

```r
x1 <- c(0,2,-4)
y1 <- c(0,4,-6)
df <- data.frame(x1,y1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) + 
    geom_vector()
```

Which prints:

[image]